# Getting JSON Response issue

Tags: ios, objective-c

Currently i am using .net Api's for getting response

Here is my iOS source code:

```
-(void)getUserNameFromFacebbok: (NSString*)newUserName withFacebookId: (NSString*)newFbId withFacebookLoginEmailId: (NSString*)newEmailId withProfilePicUrl: (NSString*)newProfilePicUrl{
NSString * fbApiURLStr =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://example.com/api/v1/FacebookUserLogin?UserName=%@&id=%@&emailid=%@&facebookurl=%@",
                       newUserName,
                       newFbId,
                       newEmailId,
                       newProfilePicUrl];

NSMutableURLRequest *dataRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:fbApiURLStr]];
NSHTTPURLResponse *response =[[NSHTTPURLResponse alloc] init];
NSError* error;
NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:dataRequest returningResponse:&response error:&error];
facebookLoginResponseDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData
                                                    options:0
                                                      error:&error];
}
```

I am not getting any response **dataRequest**  parameter ====> currently i am getting  **{ URL: (null) }**

Can you please help me out how can i solve this issue

Comment: Check with your url that you are calling and secondly you try to hit this url on postman or browser to check for response.

Comment: I want to know one thing. why you're giving  -1   count to my question. The exact problem is this:::  NSURL * url =[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://example.com/api/v1/FacebookUserLogin?UserName=%@&id=%@&emailid=%@&facebookurl=%@",
                           newUserName,
                           newFbId,
                           newEmailId,
                           newProfilePicUrl]];  =====> here i am getting {nil} ---> Why?

Comment: If i tried following Answer what ever i post --> I am getting response correctly ===> why?

Comment: NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[fbApiURLStr stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

Comment: Firstly, I didnt vote it down and Secondly, good that you got the answer.

Comment: Sorry..  nikhil84, ThanQ for you're response

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I found the proper solution like

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/api/v1/FacebookUserLogin?UserName=Brahmam&id=4654566&emailid=ghjnghjnhgh@gmail.com&facebookurl=https://fbjghjghjghjghmkjhgmhjkmhjmh"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

NSURLResponse *response;
NSError *error;
//send it synchronous
NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
// check for an error. If there is a network error, you should handle it here.
if(!error)
{
    //log response
    NSLog(@"Response from server = %@", responseString);
}
```